# Query about a script that makes webcam take an image every x seconds

Tags: scripts, webcam

I have a Trust usb webcam. I'm looking for (or creating) a script that could take a screenshot from the camera every 10 seconds and save the image to disc with a timestamp for a filename.

I've found

```
streamer -o 0000.jpeg -s 300x200 -j 100 -t 1 -r 10
```

But it only runs once and it doesn't save the filename as something unique, so when the script starts again it will override the previous files with the same name.

Any ideas on a script that can start taking timelapse photos when my machine starts up?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few solutions here, perhaps the best would be to run your command like this in one line:

```
while true; do streamer -o `date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S`.jpg -s 300x200 -j 100 -t 1 -r 10; sleep 10; done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use decimals in the rate. This works:

```
streamer -t 99999999999999 -r 0.1 -o 00000.jpeg
```

The -t argument has to be filled for some reason but the above will run for 3 billenia (yeah). You could probably lower it down a few columns.

Comment: what option is for timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fswebcam` :

With the **webcam connected and fswebcam installed**, enter the command `fswebcam` followed by a `filename` and a picture will be taken using the webcam, and saved to the filename specified:

```
fswebcam cam.jpg
```

To know more about timestamps and schedule task you can visit this site [fswebcam](http://www.raspberrypi.org/learning/webcam-timelapse-setup/)

To see manual page visit this site [Manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/fswebcam.1.html)

It is a great tool , i recommend it for this usage , you can also use it in a **script** , see the first link.

Comment: Thanks :) - works, but it is not capturing a full frame, it seems to be capturing the first and second image of a frame and fusing them together.

Comment: read more about its options